# Android Kotlin Localization

Tags: android, kotlin, configuration, localization

I am implementing localization in my android project.I have implemented dependency injection so the code looks cleaner and every class has its own small function in the localization implementation process.

THE PROBLEM:
At the first start of the application, the app uses my phone's localization (en-GB), after I change the language the app successfully changes the configuration and recreates its activity, and uses the strings.xml file which I want (in this case is strings from values-de folder). Everything works as it should, even when I exit the app and return to the app the localization is the one that I have set. The only problem is that when I force close the app and open it again. It shows the strings from the original values/strings.xml file even tho the parameters for another language are set in every method which I use when it works normally (checked by debugging).

App.kt is referenced in the manifest, strings.xml files are all translated, the LocaleHelper.kt successfully returns the context to the App with the new localization which is retrieved from SharedPreferences.

LocaleHelper.kt

```
object LocaleHelper {

     const val SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language"

    fun onAttach(context: Context): Context {
        val locale = getLocale(context)
        return setLocale(context, locale)
    }

    private fun getLocale(context: Context): Locale {
        return load(context)
    }

    fun setLocale(context: Context, locale: Locale): Context {
        persist(context, locale)

        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            updateResources(context, locale)
        } else
            updateResourcesLegacy(context, locale)
    }

    fun isRTL(locale: Locale): Boolean {
        return Locales.RTL.contains(locale.language)
    }

    private fun getPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(LocaleHelper::class.java.name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    private fun persist(context: Context, locale: Locale?) {
        if (locale == null) return
        getPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, locale.language)
            .apply()
    }

    private fun load(context: Context): Locale {
        val preferences = getPreferences(context)
        val language = preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault().language)
        return Locale(language!!)
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun updateResources(context: Context, locale: Locale): Context {

        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val configuration = context.resources.configuration

        configuration.setLocale(locale)

        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, locale: Locale): Context {
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val resources = context.resources

        val configuration = resources.configuration

        configuration.locale = locale

        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)

        return context
    }

}
```

LocaleHelperActivityDelegate.kt and LocaleHelperActivityDelegateImpl.kt

```
interface LocaleHelperActivityDelegate {
    fun setLocale(activity: Activity, newLocale: Locale)
    fun setWelcomeActivityLocale(activity: Activity, newLocale: Locale)
    fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context): Context
    fun onPaused()
    fun onResumed(activity: Activity)
    fun onCreate(activity: Activity)
}

class LocaleHelperActivityDelegateImpl : LocaleHelperActivityDelegate {

    val KEY_ACTIVITY_LOCALE_CHANGED = "activity_locale_changed"

    override fun onCreate(activity: Activity) {
        activity.window.decorView.layoutDirection =
                if (LocaleHelper.isRTL(Locale.getDefault())) View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL else View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
    }

     var locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()

    override fun setLocale(activity: Activity, newLocale: Locale) {
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(activity, newLocale)

        locale = newLocale

        activity.startActivity(activity.intent)

        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)

        activity.intent.putExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_LOCALE_CHANGED, true)

        activity.finish()

        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)

    }

    override fun setWelcomeActivityLocale(activity: Activity, newLocale: Locale) {
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(activity, newLocale)

        locale = newLocale

        activity.startActivity(activity.intent)

        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)

        activity.intent.putExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_LOCALE_CHANGED, true)

        activity.finish()

        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context): Context {
        return LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase)
    }


    override fun onPaused() {
        locale = Locale.getDefault()
    }



    override fun onResumed(activity: Activity) {

        val localeDefault = Locale.getDefault()

        val isLocaleChanged = activity.intent.getBooleanExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_LOCALE_CHANGED, false)

        if(isLocaleChanged) {
            activity.startActivity(activity.parentActivityIntent)
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)

            activity.finish()
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
        }
    }
}

class LocaleHelperApplicationDelegate {
    fun attachBaseContext(base: Context): Context {
        return LocaleHelper.onAttach(base)
    }

    fun onConfigurationChanged(context: Context) {
        LocaleHelper.onAttach(context)
    }
}
```

LocaleAwareCompatActivity.kt

```
open class LocaleAwareCompatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val localeDelegate = LocaleHelperActivityDelegateImpl()

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(localeDelegate.attachBaseContext(newBase))
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        localeDelegate.onCreate(this)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        localeDelegate.onResumed(this)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        localeDelegate.onPaused()
    }

    open fun updateLocale(locale: Locale) {
        localeDelegate.setLocale(this, locale)
    }
}
```

BaseActivity.kt which is implemented in every Activity class in the project

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val localeDelegate = LocaleHelperActivityDelegateImpl()

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(localeDelegate.attachBaseContext(newBase))
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        localeDelegate.onCreate(this)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        localeDelegate.onResumed(this)
    }


    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        localeDelegate.onPaused()
    }

    open fun updateLocale(locale: Locale) {
        localeDelegate.setLocale(this, locale)
    }

    override fun applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration: Configuration?) {
        super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration)
    }

    open fun updateWelcomeActivityLocale(locale: Locale)
    {
        localeDelegate.setWelcomeActivityLocale(this, locale)
    }
}
```

And my App class which implements Application

```
class App : Application()
{


    private val localeAppDelegate = LocaleHelperApplicationDelegate()


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Unique initialization of Cache library to allow saving into device
        CacheLibrary.init(this)

        // Unique initialization of Dependency Injection library to allow the use of application context
        startKoin { androidContext(this@App) }

        Preferences.init(this)

    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(localeAppDelegate.attachBaseContext(base))
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        localeAppDelegate.onConfigurationChanged(this)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid all the above codes by using this library. It's simple and does all the work

[Lingver](https://github.com/YarikSOffice/lingver)

Initialize the library in Application.onCreate

```
Lingver.init(context, defaultLanguage)
```

Change a locale, for instance, from your setting screen:

```
 Lingver.getInstance().setLocale(context, language)
```

Comment: not working, after set locale the language does not changed

Comment: You can see the demo project, he using recreate function after setLocale too